# Write Exif data back to image rotated by GD image library

Tags: c++, gd, libexif

I'm having trouble when try to attach original exif data back to image after rotating it by GD image.

How I rotate image

```
rotatedImage = gdImageRotateInterpolated(image, (360-rotationDeg)%360, 0);
imgBuffer = (unsigned char *)gdImageJpegPtr(rotatedImage, &imgSize, 85);
```

Then I have a function try to write extracted exif data from original image to rotated one by combine image buffer with exif buffer but I can't still see Exif data while inspecting the image. I'm using `libexif`

```
writeExifData(unsigned char* &imageBuffer, int &size, ExifData* exifData) {
    if (!exifData) {
        return;
    }
    TRACE("Image Size: %d", size);
    // save exif data into buffer
    unsigned char* buf = NULL;
    unsigned int bufSize = 0;
    exif_data_save_data(exifData, &buf, &bufSize);
    std::vector<unsigned char> combinedBuffer(size + bufSize);

    // Copy the image buffer
    std::copy(imageBuffer, imageBuffer + size, combinedBuffer.begin());

    // Copy the EXIF buffer
    std::copy(buf, buf + bufSize, combinedBuffer.begin() + size);

    unsigned char* newImageBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(combinedBuffer.size());

    memcpy(newImageBuffer, combinedBuffer.data(), combinedBuffer.size());
    imageBuffer = newImageBuffer;
    size = combinedBuffer.size();
}
```

Any other way that I can have new image buffer include all Exif data from original image?

Comment: Is the approach here really to just attach EXIF metadata to the end of the existing JPEG? Does `imageBuffer` contain any metadata still?

Comment: @Botje My goal is trying to preserve exif data after manipulating it by GD image, that's why I'm trying get Exif data before manipulating it then attach it back afterwards. So my expected result is the rotated image should have all Exif info as the original one (GPS tagging data, original date time, ...)

Comment: Unless the image is square then at the very least you will need to make sure any Exif data related to width and height are appropriately transposed. There are better libraries around that can losslessly rotate or crop a JPEG image without decoding it through image space see the [IJG](https://jpegclub.org/) webpage for details.

Comment: Good remark! Why rotate the actual image bytes when you can just update the "image orientation" tag?

Comment: That's because of laziness I would say since I have tons of Jasper report files that display image by its base64data. Thus I want to rotate the image physically so I don't need to update anything in reports but I didn't know that GD doesn't preserve Exif info at the first place so now I'm suffering. But I think I'll consider to update it. Anw your solution is more than perfect for me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JPEG image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) consists of a number of segments using tag-length-value encoding. Furthermore, APP1 data for EXIF is supposed to come right after the SOI marker in the file, which is the first two bytes of your JPEG.

`exif_save_data` produces the "value" part but you need to wrap that in a segment yourself.

Thus, you can do the following:

```
struct jpeg_header {
  uint16_t soi;
  uint16_t app1;
  uint16_t exif_len;
} jh = { htobe16(0xFFD8), htobe16(0xFFE1), htobe16(2 + bufSize) };

unsigned char* newImageBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(jh) + size - 2 /* duplicate SOI */);
unsigned char* write = newImageBuffer;
write = std::copy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&jh), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&jh) + sizeof(jh), write);
write = std::copy(buf, buf+bufSize, write);
write = std::copy(imageBuffer+2, imageBuffer+size, write);

return newImageBuffer;
```

If you do not have access to `htobe16` you can use `htons` as well.